# Regular Expression for "D210" for Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, expression, linux-mint

The tile says it all. Right now I'm using:

```
grep "^D[\d][\d][\d]" file.txt
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

`\d` is not recognized unless `-P` or `--perl-regexp` option is specified. (assuming GNU grep).

```
$ echo D210 | grep '^D\d\d\d'
$ echo D210 | grep -P '^D\d\d\d'
D210
$ echo D210 | grep -P '^D\d{3}'
D210
```

If your `grep` does not accept `-P`, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`:

```
$ echo D210 | grep '^D[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
D210
$ echo D210 | grep '^D[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]'
D210
```

Comment: I'm using Mint.
That's still not giving me output.

I'm scanning a text file with the terminal.

Comment: @user3199964, If you mean Mint linux, which is based on Ubuntu linux. `-P` option should workd.

Comment: @user3199964, Maybe `D` is not at the beginning of the line? Then remove `^`. (`^` matches only at the beginning of the line)

Comment: @user3199964, What is the output of following command? `grep -V`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. On this site, rather than posting "thank you" comments, we upvote and / or accept good answers. This will award both you and the person who helped you some reputation points; as you gain more points, you unlock more features on the site. Please make sure to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for details. Thanks!